# how to know how many elements in csv. PERL

Tags: perl

I am writing code that reads in a csv file and generates a new txt file from it. The problem is I don't know how many elements will be in its rows. for example it can be

```
1,2,3,4,6
6,7,8,9,10
```

or

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

I am using Text:CSV_XS but since it is getting the line as a variable I can't seem to be able to obtain its length.
Can someone help me with this basic issue?

```
open(OUTFILE,'>file.txt');

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });
# #fields is a variable so can't seem to do $fields_size = @fields for its length
my $fields = $csv->getline ($fh);
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)){
    for(my $c=0; $c <=1 ; $c++)
        {print OUTFILE "$fields->[$c]=$row->[$c];";}
    print OUTFILE "\n";     
}
close $fh;
```

here I assume there are only 2 elements but how can I make:

```
 for(my $c =0; $c <=$fields_size ; $c++)
```

for my loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find length of array in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744697/find-length-of-array-in-perl)

Comment: I tried  my $size = scalar @{$fields}; but I get: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string

Comment: Please read the SO documentation on code markup, so people don't have to keep editing your question to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your question was essentially, "How can I get the number of elements in an array," it looks like what you're *really* trying to do is print the column header and value for each field in your CSV.

To do this, use [Text::CSV's](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV#getline_hr) `getline_hr` instead of `getline`, which will store each row of your CSV in a hash reference. Then you don't have to keep track of array indices. The following prints each field and the associated column name in order from left to right:

```
# Set column names using first row in file
$csv->column_names($csv->getline($fh));

while (my $hr = $csv->getline_hr($fh)) {
    print "$_=$hr->{$_};" for $csv->column_names;
    print "\n";
}
```

Note that your column names must be unique.

Comment: not quite. I want the new line only after the whole row is processed. Not after each element.

Comment: which I have fixed it accordingly. Thanks this solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
my $fields = $csv->getline ($fh); 
my $size = scalar @$fields;
```

Comment: that gives me the error: "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string" as well

Comment: That error implies that `$fields` isn't set. You're doing something wrong when you assign it.

Comment: my $fields = $csv->getline ($fh); if I loop with fixed number of lengths. I think the $size doesn't get assigned.

Comment: that's what I am doing and it is erroring out. If I loop with     for(my $c=0; $c <=1 ; $c++) then it works. $size doesn't get assigned